Java QueryDSL: how could I retrieve a column only if in the group there is no null existing?
So I have a table (ORDERS):
ID     CUSTOMER_ID     LOCATION 
1           11          London 
2           null        London 
3           22          Amsterdam
4           33          Amsterdam
5           44          Berlin
6           null        Berlin
7           55          Paris
8           66          Paris

I need an sql query (java queryDSL) that returns: Amsterdam and Paris, given there is not a single entry:
where LOCATION == Amsterdam AND CUSTOMER_ID == NULL
and also:
where LOCATION == Paris AND CUSTOMER_ID == NULL
So far I have:
List<String> locations = Lists.newArrayList("London", "Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Paris");

new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
.select(orders.location)
.from(orders)
.where(orders.location.in(locations))
.groupBy(orders.location)

// I believe this is the part where I need some help
.having(...)

But if you have any other solution, I am open to hear it.
Thanks in advance!

@stacktrace2234 try this -
List<String> locations = Lists.newArrayList("London", "Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Paris");

  new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
    .select(orders.location)
    .from(orders)
    .where(orders.location.in(locations))
    .groupBy(orders.location)
    .having(
        orders.location.eq("Amsterdam").and(orders.customerId.isNull())
        .or(orders.location.eq("Paris").and(orders.customerId.isNull()))
    );


Ok, but I need something more general. The locations can be random.

then you need to create the dynamic query iterate the random locations and create the having object in a method and can call and use the same in having clause
